# Can't save file in Hebrew language

Tags: lyx, hebrew

When I try to save a file includes Hebrew latters, I get this error:
[image: log output]

I have already tried [culmusmiktex](https://wiki.lyx.org/Windows/Hebrew) Hebrew configuration.
Thanks guys :)

Comment: better use xelatex or lualatex with hebrew. The pdftex setup is mostly broken and rather difficult to correct, even outside lyx.

Answer (score 1):

It should be solved by going to Document → Settings → LaTeX Preamble, and adding \usepackage{culmus}. Then click "Save as Document Defaults".